# How do I go to a search phrase in VIM

Tags: vim

I've looked at dozens of tutorials, and they all say how to search in Vim, but not how to stay on the search result.
Let's say I'm at the top of the file, and the word cow is on line 700. If I press Esc, then /cow it will show me the word on line 700, and I can of course use n or N. But as soon as I hit Enter, or Esc, or spacebar,... it puts me back at the top of the screen.
Is there a way to search in Vim and then make the cursor go to and stay on that searched word/phrase?
Thank you.

Comment: What? typing `/cow` then pressing enter puts your cursor on that search result

Comment: Enter is supposed to place the cursor on the search result... is there something in your vim config that is overriding this behavior?

Comment: you said ... 
 "But as soon as I hit Enter, or Esc, or spacebar,..."

hitting Enter will complete the search and move the cursor to the search.
Esc is different.  It will cancel the search.
Hitting spacebar will add a space char to the end of your search.  This changes the pattern that you're searcing for.  

Please only use Enter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/cow<CR>
```

*is* how you move the cursor to the next occurrence of `cow` in normal mode.

Try again without your config:

```
$ vim --clean <file with cow on line 700>
```